# Convert RBG to HEX

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, colors

How can I convert a RGB color into a HEX in AS3?. For example: R=253 G=132 B=58.

Tks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Robusto's solution is too slow.

Because RGB values are stored like this:

```
8b Red | 8b Green | 8b Blue
```

And a value of 0-255 (that is not a coincidence) has 8b too, you can use left bitwise shifts to get the int value, and THEN you can get a hex (almost 3 times faster). So:

```
var intVal:int = red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
var hexVal:String = intVal.toString(16);
hexVal = "#" + (hexVal.length < 6 ? "0" + hexVal : hexVal);
```

Where *red*, *green* and *blue* are the values of RGB that you want to convert.

Comment: don't forget the alpha channel if you are using ARGB (ie BitmapData.getPixel32(). `alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue`

Comment: But that would be _A_RGB then, wouldn't it :D Also - this (I believe) is for more conventional use like palette picker, or a convertor for CSS / HTML usage - a colour there is ALWAYS in the format of #RRGGBB or #RGB - not alpha anywhere.

Comment: What if the R channel only has one hex digit? This returns "#40404". Most applications are looking for "#040404"

Comment: Because the actual toString(16) does not have a means to set length of the resultant string, so you have to add leading zeroes yourself. Say, you want a pure blue, blue=255, red=0, green=0. You receive a #FF as an output here, and you would want #0000FF instead. So, you take the result of `intVal.toString(16)` and check its length, and prepend zeroes until it'll be 6, then prepend a # symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the RGB numbers to hex values and concatenate them.

```
var hexVal = (253).toString(16) + (132).toString(16) + (58).toString(16);
hexVal = "#" + hexVal;
// returns "#fd843a"
```

This is less elegant than it ought to be, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: There's a bug in your code. If any component takes just one hex digit (i.e. component < 16), components to the left will end up shifted to the right one place, which will you bogus results (unless the value to the left is a zero). You'll have to zero pad each component, but at this point, you might as well just use bitshifts, I think.

Comment: @Juan Pablo: I didn't intend this to be an exhaustive solution, just an illustration of an idea, the idea being that you would convert base 10 values to base 16. I don't have time to write bug-free optimized code for other people, but more power to you if you do.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say. I apologize if my comment sounded harsh, I didn't mean it that way. I just thought it was worth mentioning that there was a problem in case someone wanted to use the posted code as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Aurel300's is pretty much the standard way, so I'd go with it. Robusto's solution, as is, is incorrect.

Another option if you want to avoid bit operations is using simple arithmetic:

```
var intVal:int = red * 0x10000 + green * 0x100 + blue;
```

or, if you think hex notation will cause confusion.

```
var intVal:int = red * 65536 + green * 256 + blue;
```

I posted this just to show you another way of getting the hex value (one that makes more clear how components work and add up to the final value, I think), but, as I said already, I'd got with Aurel300's code.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications need a six digit hex code for colors:

```
function RGBtoHEX(r, g, b) { 
    var s = (r << 16 | g << 8 | b).toString(16); 
    while(s.length < 6) s="0"+s;
    return "#"+s;
}
```